# sql query complex

Tags: sql

I have table where in a table called test which have 4 fields.one field named as listing, I have 1,2,3,4,5,6 multiple values separated by comma, I need to check whether in that table and in that particular field an id say 4 is there or not..  by a sql query.

Comment: Django has a field type called CommaSeparatedIntegerField which I think is stored in the database as text. I'm having difficulty finding how the interaction with the database for this stuff works though.

Answer (score 3):

You database design is wrong, that's why you have problems querying the data. You should have the values in a separate table, so that teach value is in it's own field. Then it would be easy to find the records:

```
select t.testId
from test t
inner join listing l on l.testId = t.testId
where l.id = 4
```

Now you have to use some ugly string comparison to find the records:

```
select testId
from test
where ','+listing+',' like '%,4,%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable 
WHERE REPLACE(Col, ' ', '') LIKE '4,%' --Starts with
OR REPLACE(Col, ' ', '') LIKE '%,4' --Ends with
OR REPLACE(Col, ' ', '') LIKE '%,4,%' --Contains
OR REPLACE(Col, ' ', '') = '4' --Equals
```

Just as a matter of interest, have a look at this

```
DECLARE @delimiter NVARCHAR(5),
        @Val INT

SELECT @Val = 40

SELECT  @delimiter = ','

DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Vals VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID,Vals) SELECT 1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Vals XML
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable 
SELECT  ID,
        CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(Vals, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML)
FROM    @YourTable 

SELECT  *
FROM    @TempTable tt
WHERE   EXISTS(
            SELECT  T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
            FROM    tt.Vals.nodes('/d') T(split)
            WHERE   T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') = @Val
)
```

Comment: and then you have to account for spaces between comma's, ... . +1 though.

Comment: You do not have to account for spaces between commas, assuming that the exact format is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to parse the list into a table variable or table-valued function, then either join against the table, or use an EXISTS sub-query.

There are lots of examples on how to do this:

http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=SQL+parse+list+into+table

Comment: This is assuming SQL Server, not sure about other RDBMS's.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instring function in the where clause and in the select clause:

Oracle:

```
select substr(column, instr(column, '1', 1), 1)
where instr(column, '1', 1) > 0
```

works if you want a single value. Alternatively you can use a combination of case or decode statements to create a single column for each possible value:

```
select 
 decode(instr(column, '1', 1), 0, substr(column, instr(column, '1', 1), 1), null) c1,
 decode(instr(column, '2', 1), 0, substr(column, instr(column, '2', 1), 1), null) c2,
 decode(instr(column, '3', 1), 0, substr(column, instr(column, '3', 1), 1), null) c3
```

The beauty of this approach for such a poorly normalised set of data is you can save this as a view and then run SQL on that, so if you save the above you could use:

```
select c1, c2 from view where c1 is not null or c2 is not null
```

NB. In other dbms you might have to use different syntax, possibly the case rather decode statement

Answer (score -1):

If you need to find 4 and only 4 (ie not 14 or 24 or 40 etc) you should use

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col LIKE '%, 4,%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col LIKE '%,4,%'
```

if there are no spaces between the commas and numbers

Comment: this is true, but personally in this situation I'd write the code that sends the string to the databse to include a comma at the start and end - or a space at the start and comma at the end and remove the first comma from the query - so that the query would always work.

Answer (score -3):

How about this?

```
Select * From Foo Where Col like '%4%'
```

Comment: or did you need to see if there were 4 ','s